# gotoAndPlay not working in compiled .swf or .air

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air, flash-cs5

I have a Flash Professional CS5 project with ActionScript 3. I have a movieclip object with several gotoAndPlay ActionScript commands inside of it. I also have other gotoAndPlay commands on the main stage, linked to interactive events.

When I run the project via Ctrl+Enter, it works perfectly, without any issues. However, once I compile it down to a .swf or an Air 3.0 file, it runs, but omits some or all of the gotoAndPlay commands, both the ones inside of and outside of the stage.

How do I fix this? (My code is extensive, but if anyone really needs to see it, I'll see what I can put together.)

Comment: That does not make much sense. When you hit Ctrl+Enter, what Flash Professional does is compiling it to an SWF. It’s actually the same compilation process which is done via the file menu, so there should not be any difference between Ctrl+Enter and the SWF directly (at least when run in the projector).

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make any sense. Yet, that is what is happening...

Comment: Ah, heh...I think it is the fact I'm using the trial. I'll be buying the full version later this month. If that fixes this, I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Actually, there was a significant (but subtle) oversight in several places in my code. The trial has no disabled features...it works just fine, even in final compiles to .swf or Air.

If you're having trouble like I was, re-read your code. There's an error there SOMEWHERE.